# Show that the functor that takes $R$ to the set of invertible elements of $R[X]/(X^2-a)$ is representable.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, representable-functor

The following question is from the Fall 2016 UCLA algebra qualifying exam:

Let $F$ be a field and $a\in F$. Show that the functor that takes $R$, commutative $F$-algebras to the invertible elements of $R[X]/(X^2-a)$ is representable.

What I have so far:
If $a\in F$, then then we have that $R[X]/(X^2-a)\cong R\times R$. Hence we get that $$ Hom_{F-\text{alg}}(F[t,t^{-1}]\otimes_FF[t,t^{-1}],R)\cong Hom_{F-\text{alg}}(F,R\times R)\cong U(R)$$ where $U$ is the functor that take $R$ to units of $R[X]/(X^2-a)$. Hence in this case, the functor is representable.

I'm unsure how to extend this to the general case.

Comment: Do you mean if $a\in F^2$?

Comment: The question says $a\in F$.

Comment: I meant after "What I have so far".

Comment: Sorry, I meant that $a$ has a square root in $F$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all observe that if $A$ is a ring then naturally
$
A^\times \cong \{(x,y)\in A^2: xy=1\}.
$

One always has $R^2\cong R[X]/(X^2-a)$ as $R$-modules via $(a_1,a_0)\mapsto a_1X+a_0$, and an element corresponding to a pair $(a_1,a_0)$ is invertible if and only if there exists $(b_1,b_0)\in R^2$ such that 
$$
(a_1b_0+a_0b_1,a_0b_0+aa_1b_1-1)=(0,0) \hspace{1cm} (\ast)
$$
The $F$-algebra $F[A_0,A_1,B_0,B_1]/(A_1B_0+A_0B_1,A_0B_0+aA_1B_1-1)$ represents the desired functor on $F$-algebras
$$
R\mapsto \{(a_1,a_0,b_1,b_0)\in R^4 \text{ satisfying } (\ast)\}\cong \{(\gamma,\delta)\in (R[X]/(X^2-a))^2 : \gamma \delta=1\}.
$$